# PouchDb <-> CouchDb Replicate

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a problem with replicate when I turn off network and after few seconds turn on network.

After turn on network I must wait on replicate sync between 3-5 minutes:

[image]

On the prod env thi can be problematic.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please don't post images, over time they end up as broken links, and more importantly it prevents those with visual impairments from helping.  Read https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html#live%E2%80%93replication it discusses the very problem you are posting about, specifically the `retry` option and the `paused` sync event.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, sorry for image.

I was read about replication in pouchdb and using retry option

My code:

```
  this.service.synch().then((data) => {
    this.lottieSpashScreen.hide();

  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('no network or couch not respond')
    this.lottieSpashScreen.hide();

  });
```

In service:

```
synch() {

let optionsToAndFrom = {
  live: true, 
  retry: true,
  continuous: true
};
this.db.replicate.to(this.remote, optionsToAndFrom)

return this.db.replicate.from(this.remote)
  .on('complete', (info) => {
    this.db.replicate.from(this.remote, optionsToAndFrom) 
  }) 
  .on('error', (info) => {
    console.log('error')
  })}
```

Sometimes if a device is disconnected a long of time , replication stop and I have to restart app.

ON the network I can see that stalled on request is over four minutes

Edit: In browser everything working okay, without problem.

Problem is on device with android

EDIT :

When I started App and network not connect I can see in log :

net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

And thats great.

But when I started app and network connect and after few seconds disconnected I can see only in network that request is in pending status without error. When I turn on network after about minutes this request exectued but when I network off after about five minutes this request is in pending without changes status.

Comment: You need to implement a custom back off function via the replication option `back_off_function`, read over [Customizing retry for replication](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#customizing-retry-replication). Everything you need is there.

Comment: I try :  live: true,
    retry: true,
    continuous: true,
    back_off_function: function (delay) {
      console.log(delay)
      if (delay === 0) {
        return 1000; 
      }
      return 5000; 
    } but it's work fine when I started app and network is off. I can see cosnole log. But when app working and I network off console is empty and replication not working.

Comment: When I started App and network not connect I can see in log :

net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

And thats great. 

But when I started app and network connect and after few seconds disconnected I can see only in network that request is in pending status without error. When I turn on network after about minutes this request exectued but when I network off after about five minutes this request is in pending without changes status. Please help

Comment: Have you tried the `heartbeat` and `timeout` advanced replication options?

Comment: I tried on other android and for Android 10 is okay. The problem is on Android 6.0.1 on Zebra device. In this moment I don't know if problem is with Android 6.0.1 or maybe with Zebra devices.